# SQL Server 2012 MDS - Limitations

Tags: sql-server, excel, mds

I am started using SQL Server 2012 MDS for maintaining our huge customer base. My question is whether MDS supports more than 10 million records? If so, how it is handled in excel? Excel has the number of rows limitation of 1 million.

Comment: This is answered in the [Maximum Capacity Specifications for SQL Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Below is Quote from [technet](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7812.master-data-services-capacity-guidelines.aspx) on same,posting relevant content here

> Create Entity: Creating an entity from an Excel table is dependent on both the number of records and the number of columns, and appears to be linear in its progression. **The number of attributes supported is based on SQL table limits, while the number of members will be constrained by Excel worksheet row limitations of 1M rows**.

Comment: How does this answer the question about the SQL server?

Comment: The question is about MDS limitations and my answer answers it